# Error: "Could not find field" in SharePoint/Access linked list

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I linked a SharePoint list to an Access table to create a more functional UI. I created queries to show the information various groups would have to update, then forms for them to use to make updates. As far as I can tell, everything worked as expected while it was on my hard drive. When I uploaded it to SharePoint for general use, it started giving a "could not find field" error seemingly randomly when users would try to update certain records.

I use SharePoint 2016, Access 2016, and Windows 10.

What I've tried:

- Comparing data types of Access/SharePoint fields
- Refreshing the table link Recreating from scratch
- Unchecking "Use the cache format that is compatible with Microsoft Access 2010 and later"
- Making fields required in SharePoint also required in Access
- Adding user info table due to created by/modified by fields (see below - not
  sure if my relationships should be changed? Does the HistoricalData table need a relationship to UserInfo?)

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be going wrong?

[Relationships View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL55c.png)

I also posted a variation on this question [here](http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=72040).

Answer (score 2):

Go To

1. File --> Options --> Current Database --> Caching Web Service and
   SharePoint tables ........
2. Uncheck the box next to “Use the cache format that is compatible
   with Microsoft Access ........”